# How to adjust background color for 'paper' on material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui

I am studying `material-ui` styling and using one of the free templates that is given.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    height: "100vh"
  },
  image: {
    backgroundImage: "url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundColor:
      theme.palette.type === "dark"
        ? theme.palette.grey[900]
        : theme.palette.grey[50],
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundPosition: "center"
  },
  paper: {
    margin: theme.spacing(8, 4),
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
  },
  form: {
    width: "100%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
  }
}));
```

I have tried touching each aspect and have tried to change the background of the right side of the template. But it just looks like it is just covering the form. How can I adjust the entire background of the space and the color of the form elements as well?

[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5xWw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn9e0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your Component code and how these styles are applied.

But in general, you can modify the colour of the paper like so:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paperRoot: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
}));
```

And then either:

```
<Paper className={classes.paperRoot} />
```

Or

```
<Paper classes={{root: classes.paperRoot}}/>
```

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-89j7p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) showing the second option.

The related guide on the mui docs is [Customizing components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components).